# How would I store a list of Facebook friends into an array for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I store the following output into an array.

[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

This is a list of Facebook friends for an iOS app and I need to store it as an NSArray I'm guessing.

thanks for any help

Comment: I think what you mean is, how do I store the OUTPUT from the request? Well, what do you get back from the request - did you log it or look at its class (NSStringFromClass([returnedObject class]);? Its probably an array. Just save the return in a NSArray ivar. Did I mess something???

Comment: I get back <FBRequest: 0x86f53d0> from NSArray *array = [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

                NSLog(@"list of friends %@", array);
you're right though. I need the output... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this recently.  Here's how I did it.

Call the request method as mentioned above:

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self]
```

The request when successful will call the delegate method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
```

This will return an NSDictionary with a key labelled 'data'.  Get the friends array by calling

```
NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Then, you can loop through that array using a standard for loop and either extract the names you want or use a custom 'Facebook friend class' that stores both the name and the id.  To store just the names do something like this:

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];    
 for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++){
    id object = [data objectAtIndex:i];
    [array addObject:[object objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```

That should give you an array of just the your friends' names.

Comment: have you been able to post to friend's walls? that's the area I'm currently having difficulty with. I can find a random friend and post to their wall. or select from all friends and send a notification. I need to be able to select from all friends and then choose one and post to their FB wall. thanks again for any help

Comment: I haven't done that yet, but there's 2 ways to do it. You can use dialogs which don't require extended permissions or you have to ask for the right extended permission and then you can use the [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:andParams:andHTTPMethod:andDelegate] call.  To see the url required, the params you need to pass and the permissions expected, see this link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ under the section "Publishing".  Remember you can replace usernames with facebookids in the url. And you get the facebookID as part of the friend object in your initial request.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *array = [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```